# Release Candidate behaving like SNAPSHOT in Maven repository

Tags: maven, repository

In development, I can reference the latest version of an artifact as 1.2.3-SNAPSHOT. Now I need the same behaviour for release candidates, i.e. I would like to be able to depend on the latest release candidate (there should also be a procedure for the developer to declare development versions as release candidates).

I am not sure how to implement this behaviour properly. Should I use an additional repository for release candidates and move development versions to this repository if the developer requests it? Or can I somehow define a "second snapshot list", like 1.2.3-RC?

Comment: did you have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15420380/5606016)?

Comment: Does something like 1.2.3-RC-SNAPSHOT behave like SNAPSHOT, or is it necessary for SNAPSHOT to be the full qualifier (like in 1.2.3-SNAPSHOT)?

Comment: no, only snapshot it treated in a special way, afaik

Answer (score 1):

You can get there be re-configure a few things:

- use a version range for the dependency
- change the updatePolicy for the repository you store the release candidates. see https://maven.apache.org/settings.html (updatePolicy). If you store the artifacts in a maven proxy usually you need to allow to overwrite releases.

Remember in a multi module build that they might upload modules before detecting a failed build (due to `mvn deploy` being a phase not a goal). You need to verify the complete build is ok before starting to upload artifacts in the maven repository. Or stage them somehow.

Remember this will most certainly prevent your builds being reproducible. Since an RC dependency might change between builds. You would need to change the version range - which is not always an issue. Ranges may work for you.

I've better experience to let developers stay on snapshots but have the CI server set an explicit version (for example using the versions plugin) prior to deployment / releasing for the dependency the artifact uses.