# Sorting an ArrayList of Major.Minor.Incremental Strings

Tags: java, sorting

I have an ArrayList of version strings that I would like to sort so that the newest is the first listed.

```
ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
items.add("4.1.0");
items.add("4.1.1");
items.add("4.1");
items.add("5.1");
items.add("4.0.1");
```

My Expected Output is:

```
5.1
4.1.1
4.1.0
4.1
4.0.1
```

When considering the values as Integers, "4.0.1" is greater than "4.1", which is not true in the case of versions.

I am thinking of using a Comparator Interface for each major, minor and incremental version. Is there an easier way of doing this?

Comment: should `4.0.1 < 4.1`  be

Comment: Yes. Since as per maven conventions, minor version takes precedence over incremental version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upen, There's a [ComparableVersion](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.3/maven-artifact/apidocs/org/apache/maven/artifact/versioning/ComparableVersion.html) class from maven for the same.

Also, take a look at this [SO conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13004443/how-does-maven-sort-version-numbers)

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Works wonders. DefaultArtifactVersion version = new DefaultArtifactVersion("4.1.2");. Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem where I had to compare versions of the same library, besides number I had to make sure that the comparison took into account SNAPSHOT vs release point versions. After trying to come up with all the corner cases I decided not to re-invent the wheel and decided to look for a trusted implementation to solve the same problem.

I found the maven [ComparableVersion](https://github.com/apache/maven/blob/master/maven-artifact/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/artifact/versioning/ComparableVersion.java) source code and put it in my project since I didn't want to depend in that maven jar in my code.

Hope it helps for you!

Jose Luis

Answer (score 0):

Read some about maven version & Project Dependencies from Maven: 
The Complete Reference book

http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-project-dependencies.html