# What maven goal can be used for version comparison?

Tags: java, maven, versioning

Let say that there is 2 versions `A` and `B`. No matter what exactly they are. How they can be compared with maven? For example:

```
mvn someGoal A B
```

result to `A is old then B`. E.g. can maven check version from command line?

Comment: versions of what? can you give an example of a use case?

Comment: what is A and B ?

Comment: not sure it would be exactly what you need but maybe you mean something like http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/display-dependency-updates.html

Comment: You can compare things like this: `1.3.2` with `1.3.2-RC1`? Do you mean something like this?

Comment: `what is A and B ?` Seems you want to analyze versions by your mind? That is what I do **not** want to do :) Just pass two versions, add or modify [comparison rule](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/rule.html) and see how itreally works.

Comment: Please pass both the versions and then perform your operations : ADD, MODIFY etc. As suggested by @Cherry you can refer this link:  http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/rule.html

Comment: Do you really want a Maven goal? Or invoking `java` [like shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37875486/1743880) is good? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

It is not answer for original question, but good workaround. You can just checkou then maven [sources](https://github.com/apache/maven) with rigth version and then run `org.apache.maven.artifact.versioning.ComparableVersion#main` from command line, ide, not matter. It display normilized version number, and compare version in passed arguments - very good tool. :)

Answer (score 0):

The mentoined way of @Cherry is to use the command line like this:

```
java -jar apache-maven-3.3.9/lib/maven-artifact-3.3.9.jar 1.3.2 1.3.2-RC1

Display parameters as parsed by Maven (in canonical form) and comparison result:
1. 1.3.2 == 1.3.2
   1.3.2 > 1.3.2-RC1
2. 1.3.2-RC1 == 1.3.2-rc-1
```

Answer (score 0):

The mentoined way of @Cherry is to use the command line like this:

```
java -jar apache-maven-3.3.9/lib/maven-artifact-3.3.9.jar 1.3.2 1.3.2-RC1

Display parameters as parsed by Maven (in canonical form) and comparison result:
1. 1.3.2 == 1.3.2
   1.3.2 > 1.3.2-RC1
2. 1.3.2-RC1 == 1.3.2-rc-1
```

See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37875486/1743880