# Maven - Artifactory: update dependencies with buildNumber

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, artifactory, versions-maven-plugin

I have started to working at a company where they use the buildNumber concept. They open a release branch, with version set to 1.0.2-build1 for example.

The next time they generate the artifact and deploy it, they increment this number, so 1.0.2-build2.

When the code is ready to deploy to production environment, they eliminate the -buildNumber and a new tag is generated.

If we have the version 1.2.0-build7 and version 1.2.0 with the artifacts generated under Jfrog Artifactory, the last version avaiable is 1.2.0 but Maven with artifactory, if I try to use the versions plugin to update the dependency version from my pom.xml, the plugin understand that the last version is 1.2.0-build7 and not the last tag generated previusly.

Do someone know how to deal with this situation?. I´m struggling with it but without success.

Thanks to all!

Comment: You should ideally use SNAPSHOTS, not sure why you would use this specific versioning.

Comment: We use the gitflow model at this moment. With SNAPSHOTS we manage the versioning of feature branchs. When the feature is finished, we started a release branch without SNAPSHOT and the -BuildNumber concept, the same for hotfix

Comment: In Maven we should have 1.2.0-build7 < 1.2.0, as described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37871662/how-does-the-central-repository-sort-version-numbers/37875486#37875486

Comment: Maven understand 1.2.0 and 1.2.0-build7 like releases version. For my client a version with buildNumber is not a final release so i had to include a xml file with one exception to exclude the versions with build using the "rulesUri" configuration from maven plugin versions